# how do I make reference to the next three divs without creating JS objects for every div and then write code to switch the classes between each div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

My problem:
        I am trying to make a function to move the classes("prev", "current", and "next") from three divs to the next three "menuItem" divs on keydown of the down arrow key (keycode 40). The only problem is **how do I make reference to the the next three divs without creating JS objects for every div and then writing code to switch the classes between each div? Is there anyway I can do this?** jQuery UI has [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/) switch class method that will help switch classes. I can switch classes amongst the divs that are given the class attribute "prev", "current", and "next," no problem. It's switching the "next" class to the next div that is the problem. I thought one way of doing it is to reference index or rather the index of the item after the div with the "next" class attribute, but haven't figured out how to do that.

example HTML:

```
<div class ="menu">
    <div>content</div>
    <div class ="menuItem prev">content</div>
    <div class ="menuItem current">content</div>
    <div class ="MenuItem next">content</div>
    <div class="MenuItem">content</div>
    <div class ="MenuItem">content</div>
    <div>content</div>
</div>
```

example JS:

```
function handleArrowKeydown(e){
                event.preventDefault();
                var scrollPos = menu.scrollTop();
                var prevItem = $(".previous"); 
                var currentItem = $(".current");
                var nextItem = $(".next");


                function classUpdater () {
                    prevItem.removeClass('previous');
                    currentItem.addClass('previous');
                    nextItem.addClass('current');
                    currentItem.removeClass('current');
                    return; 
                }

                //code to execute on keydown of up arrow key
                if (e.keyCode == '38'){

                    menu.animate({
                        "scrollTop":( scrollPos - 240) 
                    }, 300);
                }
                //code to execute on keydown of down arrow key
                else if (e.keyCode == '40'){
                    menu.animate({
                        "scrollTop":( scrollPos + 240)
                    }, 300);
                    console.log("down arrow pressed");
                }
            } 
            zoom.on({
                "MozMousePixelScroll": handleMouseScroll,
                "mousewheel": handleMouseScroll
            });
            window.addEventListener("keydown", handleArrowKeydown, false);

    });
```

Comment: have you looked at the .next() method in jquery? you could use $(this).next(".menuitem") to get the next div on the DOM.

Comment: No, I didn't even think to see if there was a next() method, although  am no stranger to DOM traversal in jQuery. I will remember these methods though! I am still early in my coding career and i think the more i make websites and the larger my codebase gets I'll have a better time remembering some of these methods, but do you not often times find yourself looking up methods when you forget? The backend coder that taught me once told me he has learned so many languages he often finds himself googling methods.

Comment: after 7 years and a mix of C#, VB, VBScript, JQuery, PHP, SQL, and probably others, I have learned that software development is more about learning logic and how to handle certain events. Learn your syntax, usually something like C, and know where to look at the different frameworks. I probably know a good 30% of each of the languages I use, and all the websites to find the specifics. Don't worry about mastering a language, master logic and programming best practices instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a working jsiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvFWU/) that makes use of the `next()` and `prev()` selectors to move the classes between elements. (Click in the result panel then use the up and down arrows. This also repeats if you hold the arrow key down.)

And here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class ="menu">
    <div>content</div>
    <div class ="menuItem prev">content</div>
    <div class ="menuItem current">content</div>
    <div class ="menuItem next">content</div>
    <div class="menuItem">content</div>
    <div class ="menuItem">content</div>
    <div>content</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up arrow
            e.preventDefault();

            var menu = $("div.menu");

            //get the current prev div
            var prev = menu.find("div.prev");

            //get the next prev div
            var nextprev = prev.prev();

            //see if we can move up any more
            if (nextprev.length > 0) {
                //move the prev class
                prev.removeClass("prev");
                nextprev.addClass("prev");

                //move the current class
                menu.find("div.current")
                    .removeClass("current")
                    .prev()
                    .addClass("current");

                //move the prev class
                menu.find("div.next")
                    .removeClass("next")
                    .prev()
                    .addClass("next");
            }
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 40) { //down arrow
            e.preventDefault();

            var menu = $("div.menu");

            //get the current next div
            var next = menu.find("div.next");

            //get the next next div
            var nextnext = next.next();

            //see if we can move down any more
            if (nextnext.length > 0) {
                //move the next class
                next.removeClass("next");
                nextnext.addClass("next");

                //move the current class
                menu.find("div.current")
                    .removeClass("current")
                    .next()
                    .addClass("current");

                //move the prev class
                menu.find("div.prev")
                    .removeClass("prev")
                    .next()
                    .addClass("prev");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.prev { 
    color: red;
}

.current {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.next {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jQuery selectors?

```
$(this).next("div") // will return the next div
$(this).prev("div") // will return the previous div
$(this).next().next() // will return the element after the next element
```

jQuery has a lot of useful tools for DOM traversing, like parent(), find(), child(), prev(), and next(). Use them to your advantage but don't forget to include jQuery if you haven't already.

Comment: Would the $(this) selector be the current menu item and then .next and .prev are the divs below and above respectively? I haven't made use of "this" selector all that much but I am using jQuery. I have used child  parent and find but didn't even think too look if there was a prev() or next() selector.